# Can I mock a jdbcTemplate method call, when JdbcTemplate object is locally instantiated in my method?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-test, springmockito

Is there any way that I can mock a JdbcTemplate method call from my method, in which jdbc object is locally declared in the method?

```
class MyClassToBeTested{
  DataSource mydataSource;

  public void methodToBeTested(){
  JdbcTemplate template =new JdbcTemplate(mydataSource);
   template.query(...);
   }
  }
```

I am writing test case for this method and want to mock the actual call to database through template.query(...), had JdbcTemplate been on instance level in source code, I could have mocked the JdbcTemplate object and this method call, is there any way to do this?
I could use H2 database, in case of not mocking jdbcTemplate, but is there any other way too?

Comment: It's time to refactor the code.

Comment: Nope, you cannot